# Widcard .* in Vim Use

Tags: vim

I have the following data point (longitude):

```
+40 46'N +014 15'E
+21 17'N -157 52'W
```

Using Vim in Linux. I would like to use the `%s/..` function **once** to get rid of all the trailing direction indicators (`N`, `W`, `E`, `S`) and its data point to give me the following:

```
+ ' + '
+ ' - '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
:%s/[^+\-']//g
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
:%s,[^+\-\' ],,g
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
:%!perl -pe 's@(\d+ \d+|N|W|E|S)@@g'
```

- any external command can modify the current file in vim with `:%!`
- in the `Perl` command, the substitution delimiter is `@`